# Tensor Padding Pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor, dimensions

Good evening,
I am having a little trouble with the dimensions of some tensors and I would like to pad them with rows of 0s but I am not managing to do it.
My tensors are of size X by 8 and I want to add rows of 0s (of 8 elements each) until they reach the same size as the tensor with the largest amount of rows in a list.
I've obtained the maximum size with:

```
max([x.size() for x in dataset])
```

But I am lost on how to pad the rows.
Thanks a lot for your help.
Pd: Just in case, here is one example of one of my tensors:

```
tensor([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Desired output if the tensor would have 2 more rows:

```
tensor([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Comment: Could you provide the desired result associated with this tensor?

Comment: @Ivan I ve just edited the post with an example output result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize the [`torch.nn.functional.pad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/) function:

```
x = torch.tensor([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                  [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                  [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                  [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Given a maximum number of rows, `rows` (here `rows = 6`):

```
>>> F.pad(x, (0,0,0,rows-len(x)), value=0)
tensor([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```